# Access Windows Form from a Folder

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have the following folder hierarchy inside my solution folder:

```
Solution Name
    - Program.cs
    - Folder 1
        - File1.cs
```

How can I run the File1.cs (Windows Form) inside the Program.cs?

I tried updating the syntax inside the Program.cs file:

`Application.Run(Solution_Name.Folder_1.File.cs);` but it's not working.

Solution:

The syntax I was looking for is:

`Application.Run(new Solution_Name.Folder_1.File1());`

Comment: What's `File1`? is it your form?

Comment: @KingKing Yes, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem looks with correct path.

1- First check the namespace where form is located. open the File1.cs and see what name space it is in.
2- Use the full path to form `Application.Run(new Solution_Name.Folder_1.File());`

The syntax looks correct but there may be issue with namespace where you are looking for in question form.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

```
 Application.Run(new  File1());
```

I am able to run it succesfully

or you can also add

```
  using Solution_Name.Folder_1;
```

I dont think there can exist more than one form with the same name irrespective of it's location

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
//Suppose your File1 form class has the same name with the File1.cs containing it.
Application.Run(new Folder_1.File1());
```

Or even better, you should add some `using declaration` and access your `File1` class directly like this:

```
using Folder_1;
//...
Application.Run(new File1());
```

**NOTE**: each folder in the project will be treated as a `namespace`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Application.Run(new projectName.folderName.Form1());
```